# How to Remove the reports from salesforce dashboards when the report has no records,

Tags: apex, lightning, community, reporting, dashboard

How to Remove the reports from salesforce dashboards when the report has no records, the user doesnot want to see the report on the dashboard if there is no data in the report??

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to delete reports in bulk because the Report sObject does not allow DML operations to because the Report sObject does not allow DML operations to be run on it.